# Script works on its own but not in addon

Tags: python, add-on, error

I'm new to Python. This script works as it is but when I try to add it to an addon it doesn't work.
I searched a bit and some pages say that it is related to context.

You can see the purpose of this in this short [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/vKDtkjDPT0o).

Here is the full script:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

#Edit mode

bpy.ops.mesh.duplicate() # duplicate selected vertex to get position in unity based on this vertex.
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='SELECTED') # Seperate vertex, creates new object. 

mode = bpy.context.active_object.mode  # change to object mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
orijinalName = bpy.context.object.name # Save original object name
seperatedObj = bpy.context.selected_objects[1] # Save duplicated object

bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='ARROWS', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1)) #Create Empty Object
emptyObj = bpy.context.object # Save empty obj
emptyObj.name = "a" # Change the name of Empty obj

seperatedObj.parent = emptyObj # Parent seperated object to empty object

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')  # Deselect all
bpy.data.objects[orijinalName + ".001"].select_set(True) # Select only duplicated object
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = seperatedObj # Mark selected object as active

keyCount=len( bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks.keys()) # Get shape key count

shapeKeyStartIndex = 1 # Start from one cuz we dont count basis
for x in range(keyCount-1): # Same reason with upper explanation
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate()  # duplicate seperated vertex
    obj = bpy.context.object # save the new duplicated obj as obj
    obj.name = bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[shapeKeyStartIndex].name   # change the name of the obj as shapekey[index].name 
    bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 0 # change active shape key index to 0
    for y in range (shapeKeyStartIndex): # remove shape keys from 0 to "y" times to desired index become new basis
        bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=False) # remove operator
    shapeKeyStartIndex +=1   # increase index value of shape key
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') # clean selection
    bpy.data.objects[orijinalName + ".001"].select_set(True) # select first seperated obj again new loop
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = seperatedObj # mark as acite selected obj again for new loop

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') # at last clean selection
bpy.data.objects[orijinalName + ".001"].select_set(True) # select first seprated obj
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = seperatedObj # mark as active
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False) # remove from scene.
```

Here is the addon script:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Shape Key For Game Objects",
    "author": "Turkeys Place Art",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (3, 2, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Object",
    "description": "Helps Creating Pose to Pose Animation for Game",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Shape Keys",
}

import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu, Operator

import bmesh

class ShapeKeyReadyUI(bpy.types.Panel):
    
    bl_label ="Shape Keys For Game Objects"
    bl_idname = "ShapeKeyReady"
    bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_context = "data"
    
    def draw(self,context):
        
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()   
        row.operator("mesh.shapekeyreadyforgame")
        
        row1 = layout.row()
        row1.operator("object.shapefrommixforgame")
                                
        row4 = layout.row()
        row4.operator("object.shapekeyclear")
        
        
        row5 = layout.row()
        row5.operator("object.createvertexobjects")
        
class ShapeKeyPieMenu(Menu):
    bl_label = "Skip to Shape Keys"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        pie.operator("object.idle")
        pie.operator("object.interaction")
        pie.operator("object.movement") 
        pie.operator("object.hurt")
        pie.operator("object.death")
        pie.operator("object.attack")
        pie.operator("object.special") 
        pie.operator("object.other") 
        
class ShapeKeyOverallPieMenu(Menu):
    bl_label = "Shape Keys For Game"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        
        pie.operator("object.previousshapekey")
        pie.operator("object.nextshapekey")
        
        op = pie.operator("wm.call_menu_pie", text = "Skip To")
        op.name = "ShapeKeyPieMenu"
        
        pie.operator("scene.cursorrotationzero")

class ShapeKeyReady(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "mesh.shapekeyreadyforgame"
    bl_label = "Shape Key Ready"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.shape_key_add(from_mix=False)
        names = ['0_Idle.','1_Interaction.', '2_Movement.', '3_Hurt.','4_Death.', '5_Attack.', '6_Special.', '7_Other.']

        i = 0

        for nameX in names:
            if nameX == names[-1]:
                for x in range(30):
                    bpy.ops.object.shape_key_add(from_mix=False)
                    bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = i + 1
                    bpy.data.shape_keys["Key"].key_blocks["Key " + str(i +1)].name = nameX + str(x)
                    i+=1
            else:
                for x in range(10):
                    bpy.ops.object.shape_key_add(from_mix=False)
                    bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = i + 1
                    bpy.data.shape_keys["Key"].key_blocks["Key " + str(i +1)].name = nameX + str(x)
                    i+=1
                
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
class Cursor3DRotationZero(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scene.cursorrotationzero"
    bl_label = "3D Cursor Rotation Reset"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler[0] = 0
        bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler[1] = 0
        bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler[2] = 0
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
class NextShapeKey(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "object.nextshapekey"
    bl_label = "Next Shape Key"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        sKeyIndex = bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index
        bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[sKeyIndex].value=0
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = sKeyIndex +1
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
class PreviousShapeKey(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "object.previousshapekey"
    bl_label = "Previous Shape Key"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        sKeyIndex = bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index
        bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[sKeyIndex].value=0
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = sKeyIndex -1
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
class ShapeFromMixForGame(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "object.shapefrommixforgame"
    bl_label = "Continue From Here As New Shape Key"


    def execute(self, context):
        sKeyIndex = bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = sKeyIndex +1

        name = bpy.data.objects[0].active_shape_key.name

        bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=False)
        bpy.ops.object.shape_key_add(from_mix=True)
        bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[sKeyIndex].value=0

        bpy.data.objects[0].active_shape_key.name = name

        for x in range(99 - sKeyIndex):
            bpy.ops.object.shape_key_move(type='UP')
            
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
class IdleKey(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "object.idle"
    bl_label = "Skip to Idle"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 1
        return {"FINISHED"}
class InteractionKey(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "object.interaction"
    bl_label = "Skip to Interaction"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 11
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
class MovementKey(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "object.movement"
    bl_label = "Skip to Movement"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 21
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
    
class HurtKey(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "object.hurt"
    bl_label = "Skip to Hurt"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 31
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
class DeathKey(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "object.death"
    bl_label = "Skip to Death"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 41
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
class AttackKey(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "object.attack"
    bl_label = "Skip to Attack"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 51
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
class SpecialKey(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "object.special"
    bl_label = "Skip to Special"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 71
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
class OtherKey(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "object.other"
    bl_label = "Skip to Other"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 81
        return {"FINISHED"}

class ClearAllShapeKeys(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "object.shapekeyclear"
    bl_label = "Clear Shape Keys"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.context.object.shape_key_clear()
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
    
class CreateVertexObjects(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "object.createvertexobjects"
    bl_label = "Create Vertex Obj for GameObj-Pos"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.duplicate() # duplicate selected vertex to get position in unity based on this vertex.
        bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='SELECTED') # Seperate vertex, creates new object. 

        mode = bpy.context.active_object.mode  # change to object mode
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        orijinalName = bpy.context.object.name # Save original object name
        seperatedObj = bpy.context.selected_objects[1] # Save duplicated object

        bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='ARROWS', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1)) #Create Empty Object
        emptyObj = bpy.context.object # Save empty obj
        emptyObj.name = "a" # Change the name of Empty obj

        seperatedObj.parent = emptyObj # Parent seperated object to empty object

        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')  # Deselect all
        bpy.data.objects[orijinalName + ".001"].select_set(True) # Select only duplicated object
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = seperatedObj # Mark selected object as active

        keyCount=len( bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks.keys()) # Get shape key count

        shapeKeyStartIndex = 1 # Start from one cuz we dont count basis
        for x in range(keyCount-1): # Same reason with upper explanation
            bpy.ops.object.duplicate()  # duplicate seperated vertex
            obj = bpy.context.object # save the new duplicated obj as obj
            obj.name = bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks[shapeKeyStartIndex].name   # change the name of the obj as shapekey[index].name 
            bpy.context.object.active_shape_key_index = 0 # change active shape key index to 0
            for y in range (shapeKeyStartIndex): # remove shape keys from 0 to "y" times to desired index become new basis
                bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove(all=False) # remove operator
            shapeKeyStartIndex +=1   # increase index value of shape key
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') # clean selection
            bpy.data.objects[orijinalName + ".001"].select_set(True) # select first seperated obj again new loop
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = seperatedObj # mark as acite selected obj again for new loop

        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') # at last clean selection
        bpy.data.objects[orijinalName + ".001"].select_set(True) # select first seprated obj
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = seperatedObj # mark as active
        bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False) # remove from scene.

        # we have 1 orijinal mesh and other vertex objects up to orijinal meshes shapeKey count 

        return {"FINISHED"}
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ShapeKeyReadyUI)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ShapeKeyReady)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Cursor3DRotationZero)
    bpy.utils.register_class(NextShapeKey)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PreviousShapeKey)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ShapeFromMixForGame)
    bpy.utils.register_class(IdleKey)
    bpy.utils.register_class(InteractionKey)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MovementKey)
    bpy.utils.register_class(HurtKey)
    bpy.utils.register_class(DeathKey)
    bpy.utils.register_class(AttackKey)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SpecialKey)
    bpy.utils.register_class(OtherKey)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ClearAllShapeKeys)
    bpy.utils.register_class(CreateVertexObjects)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ShapeKeyPieMenu)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ShapeKeyOverallPieMenu)
    

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ShapeKeyReadyUI)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ShapeKeyReady)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Cursor3DRotationZero)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NextShapeKey)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PreviousShapeKey)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ShapeFromMixForGame)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(IdleKey)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(InteractionKey)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MovementKey)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HurtKey)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DeathKey)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AttackKey)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SpecialKey)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OtherKey)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ClearAllShapeKeys)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CreateVertexObjects)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ShapeKeyPieMenu)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ShapeKeyOverallPieMenu)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    
    
  #  bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="ShapeKeyPieMenu")
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="ShapeKeyOverallPieMenu")
```

This is the error:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
ShapeKeyReady", line 253, in execute
IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[index]: index 14 out of range, size 10
```

Comment: It would make sense to share the code that has the problem in it, if you want to get help. You said the code does not work in an add-on - could you share the code where you put it in an add-on then?

Comment: Sory for the late response, i add the addon script, that was my bad. And the error. Ive tried so many things. I can fix this error but other errors pops up. Like title says script works as its own. Not working on the addon.

Comment: There isn't necessarily something wrong with your Add-on code. The line where you get the error tries to access the first shape key of the active object. I have a distinct feeling that while you're executing this Add-on, the active object might not have any shape keys. This can easily happen because you try to find that object by constructing a name you assume it will have after duplication here `bpy.data.objects[orijinalName + ".001"].select_set(True)`, but since you are testing a lot that object name might be taken already by a different object.

Comment: So the problem is. operators run by the addon is not dynamic as i understand.  Any suggestion ?